# Auto triggering of storage menu in settings menu on Android device

Tags: android, storage, settings

On my FP3 phone (Android 11), when I go in the settings menu, the storage submenu is automaticly launched after approximatively 500ms, and the storage cache is automaticly emptied after the same interval. Exactly as if ghost clicks were made.
When I go back, the same occurs again and again.

I have just the time to chose another submenu but it is quite difficult to do.
I didn't find any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has disappeared after making some space on the device.
It seems that it's a question of storage capacity threshold which is too low for some applications (I guess).
Before I got the problem (one or two days before), the system popped up a notification about low capacity storage, so I made some space until the notification disappeared (around 2Gb). But it seems it was not enough from the point of view of the settings app, because only after removing 2 more Gb the problem disappeared. As if the threshold for the settings menu was not the same level than the one for the system.